# what is the importance of push(po[i]-'0') in the following snippet for evaluating postfix expression

Tags: c++, postfix-mta

Implement C++ program for expression conversion as infix to postfix and its evaluation using stack based on given conditions
Operands and operator, both must be single character.
Input Postfix expression must be in a desired format.
Only '+', '-', '*' and '/ ' operators are expected
I do not understand what is the importance of push(po[i]-'0') statement in the function evaluate()

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class stack
{
    char st[20],in[20],po[20];
    int TOP,k;
public:
    stack()
    {
        TOP=-1;
        k=0;
    }
    void infixToPostfix();
    void evaluate();
private:
    void push(char);
    char pop();
    int precedence(char);
};  

void stack::push(char ch)
{
    if(TOP==19) 
    {
        cout<<"Stack overflow"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        TOP++;
        st[TOP]=ch;
    }
}

char stack::pop()
{
    if(TOP==-1)
    {
        cout<<"Stack underflow"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int m=st[TOP];
        TOP--;
        return m;
    }
}

void stack::evaluate()
{
    cout<<"The postfix expression is"<<endl<<po<<endl;;
    int a,b,res,temp;
    TOP=-1;
    for(int i=0;po[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(po[i])==1)
        {
            push(po[i]-'0');
        }
        else 
        {
            a=pop();
            b=pop();
            switch(po[i])
            {
                case '+': res=b+a;
                        break;
                case '-': res=b-a;
                        break;
                case '*': res=b*a;
                        break;
                case '/': res=b/a;
                        break;
            }
            push(res);  
        }
    }
    temp=pop();
    cout<<"The answer is "<<temp<<endl;
}

void stack::infixToPostfix()
{
    int m;
    char left='(',right=')';
    cout<<"Enter infix expression"<<endl;       
    cin>>in;
    for(int i=0;in[i]!='\0';i++)        //if operand add it to postfix
    {
        if(isalpha(in[i])==1 || isdigit(in[i]==1))
        {
            po[k]=in[i];
            k++;
        }
        else if(in[i]==left)        //if left parenthesis then push it to stack;
        {
            push(left);
        }
        else if(in[i]==right)       //if right parenthesis encountered then pop from stack until left parenthesis
        {
            while((m=pop())!=left)
            {
                po[k]=m;
                k++;    
            }
        }
        else            //if operator is encounterd pop from the stack the operands having equal or higher precedence
        {
            while(precedence(st[TOP])>=precedence(in[i]))
            {
                int m=pop();
                po[k]=m;
                k++;
            }
            push(in[i]);    
        }
    }
    while(TOP>=0)
    {
        po[k]=pop();
        k++;
    }
    po[k]='\0';
    cout<<"The postfix expression is"<<endl;
    cout<<po;
}

int stack::precedence(char ch)
{
    if(ch=='+' || ch=='-')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(ch=='*' || ch=='/')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if(ch=='(')
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    stack s;
    int op;
    do
    {
        cout<<"\n____________________________"<<endl;
        cout<<"1 Postfix to infix conversion"<<endl;    
        cout<<"2 Evaluation of postfix"<<endl;
        cout<<"3 Exit"<<endl;
        cout<<"______________________________"<<endl;
        cin>>op;
        switch(op)
        {
            case 1: s.infixToPostfix();
                break;
            case 2: s.evaluate();
                break;
            case 3:break;
            default: cout<<"Enter correct option"<<endl;
        }
    }while(op!=3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I removed unneeded deep indentations from the code example. This makes it a bit easier to read. Also added some newlines after the functions to easier see where they begin and end. Try to use the preview when you post a question/answer and see what can be improved before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It converts the digit character into digit(integer). for e.g.

```
if po[i] = '5'.

It pushes, '5'-'0' => 53-48 (their ascii values) = 5.
```

cheers.